# "expo" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file

Tags: react-native, expo

Im new to React Native and expo, when runing the tutorial in [expo  docs.](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app/)
and having problems in the line
`npx expo install react-dom react-native-web @expo/webpack-config`

Im using Windows 10, and npm 10.1.0, i couldn´t find a recent issue that helps me

```
Need to install the following packages:
expo@49.0.16
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript 
standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead. 
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the 
ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.18.9: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
"expo" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.
```

Before this im running

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Programiges:ng_Scripts\React_Native>npx create-expo-app
Need to install the following packages:
create-expo-app@2.1.1
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ What is your app named? ... my-app
√ Downloaded and extracted project files.
> npm install
[..................] \ idealTree: t[#########.........] | 
idealTree: t[#########.........] | reify:my-app
added 1 package in 2s

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd my-app
- npm run android
- npm run ios # you need to use macOS to build the iOS project - use the Expo app if you need to do iOS development 
without a Mac
- npm run web

C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Programing_Scripts\React_Native>cd my-app
```